# ASP.NET(MVC) бесплатный?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте. Возникла необходимость создать сайт и больше всего мне подходит ASP.NET(MVC). Он полностью бесплатный, без лицензий и прочего? У меня есть триальная версия JetBrains Rider. Если я в нем сделаю сайт на ASP.NET(MVC) и залью его на хостинг, буду получать с него прибыль, то должен ли я буду что-то Microsoft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Привет!
Сам фреймворк вы можете использовать без какой-либо оплаты. Как и ваш код.

Оплата идёт за

- Хостинг
- Домен

Либо если у вас свой сервер

- За лицензию Windows (если сервер на Windows)
- MS Sql Server (есть и его бесплатная версия, но там есть ограничения)

Если вы используете в своём коде платные библиотеки или компоненты, в этом случае уже зависит от лицензии. Обычно оплата фиксирования или в год/месяц за использование. Сам .NET Framework, .NET Core никаких оплат не требует.

Кроме того может быть оплата за саму среду разработки VisualStudio, но можно и бесплатную поставить VisualStudio Community. Ну в случае с Rider, там бесплатная версия только для не коммерческих OpenSource проектов.

Вообще подобная ситуация со всеми языками, как я знаю, не слышал что использование какого-либо языка было платным или требовала специальных лицензий.

Так же добавлю для ясности что JetBrains Rider это продукт авторства JetBrains и к Microsoft он не имеет отношения.

Comment: Не язык, а фреймворк.

Comment: @Alex78191 спасибо, исправил